# extend a right floating div to the left

Tags: html, css

I am trying to extend a right floating div to the left.
I have an image and would like to put some text on the right of the image.
EDIT
the goal is that the site stays dynamic. So I can not use a fixed width.
One way would be to use Javascript, I guess but I would prefer to do this in HTML CSS only if possible.

Here is a picture of what I have
[image: current design]
And here is a picture of what I would like to have
[image: design goal]

How can I extend the right div to left ?
Or should I use a div in the middle ?

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="logo_container">
    <div id="logo_image">
    <img src="../img/KI_Logo_Long_FINAL.png" width="439" height="150" alt="KI-consult logo rectangle"> 
    </div> <!-- div id="logo_image" -->
    <div id="logo_address" height="150">
    test<br>address 1 <br>address2
    </div> <!-- div id="logo_address" -->
</div>  <!-- div id="logo_container" -->
```

and the CSS

```
#logo_container

{
padding: 0px; 
overflow: hidden; 
zoom: 1;

}


#logo_image

{
float: left;
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid red;

}


#logo_address

{
background-color: #0E4194;
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-left: auto; 
padding: 0px; 
float: right;
border: 1px solid red;
height: 150px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#logo_address
{
background-color: #0E4194;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 0px; 
textalign: right;
float: left;
border: 1px solid red;
height: 150px;
width: ENTER VALUE HERE;
}
```

This would be a solution. If you float the #logo_address to the left, align the text to the right and enter a width value it would look as you want.

Comment: I would like to not use a width so that the site can be dynamic according to screen width of the device displaying the site.
will edit my original post to state this.

Comment: @anatak width: calc(100% - 439px); This will give you a 100% width of the screen on any device.

Comment: @JouriSmits: thank you very much. I was not aware about calc().

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the background color on `#logo_container` rather than `#logo_address`. This will give the background color to the entire wrapper div, including the space between both child elements.

Comment: if I use the background-color on the #logo_container the rounded side of the logo with the globe will be lost.

Comment: Only if you need transparency on that image. Set the background-color for `#logo-image` to match the body background-color. You'll have an easier time fiddling with that, and the result will be more responsive than setting fixed widths for several divs.